# ¿Cómo puedo usar operadores de comparación en una consulta de campos json con laravel?

Tags: laravel, json, eloquent

Tengo una tabla llamada `arreglos` en la base de datos, en dicha tabla tengo un campo de tipo JSON que se llama `estados` y maneja un array de objetos lo cual está estructurado de la siguiente manera:

```
[{
"estado_id": 1,
"estado_precio": "1200"
},
{
"estado_id": 2,
"estado_precio": "500"
},
{
"estado_id": 3,
"estado_precio": "300"
}]
```

Lo que realmente necesito es listar los valores de la tabla solo si se cumple la condición de que `estado_precio` sea `<=` a 500.

He intentado usar `->where('estados->estado_precio', '<=', '500')`...

Y también he intentado usar `->whereJsonContains('estados', ['estado_precio' <= '500'])`, pero tampoco me da el resultado que quiero, siempre terminado listándome todos registros de la tabla.

Comment: Esto `'estados->estado_precio` no parece lo adecuado desde que tus *objetos* están dentro de un array y antes deberías acceder a ellos iterando para poder usar esa clave en la comparación que deseas hacer

Comment: debe hacer la comparación directo desde el objeto, mysql no permite comparar json y por ende recuerda que el orm es una entidad del sistema apuntando a la bd, la verdad optaria por cambiar la estructura de tu tabla a un pivote